# How to make it so that after naving to a fragment, the last fragment can no longer be navigated to with the back button?

Tags: android, android-jetpack

I have a nav structure like so:

```
StaringFragment -> nestedNavGraph
                         |
                   HomeFragment -> SecondFragment
```

I need to make it so that after the user navigates away from `StartingFragment` to the `nestedNavGraph` the user can no longer hit the back button to return to the `StartingFragment`.

I am basically performing a permissions check, and if the check succeeds I navigate from the `StartingFragment` to the `nestedNavGraph` with this code:

`findNavController(R.id.nav_host_frag).navigate(R.id.nestedNavGraph)`

Then, on the action arrow between the `StartingFrag -> nestedNavGraph` in the nav graph editor, I set `popUpTo` to `HomeFragment` and inclusive to `true`. Did I misunderstand the documentation?

What's the proper way to remove the `StartingFragment` from the backstack as soon as I navigate away from it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started#pop), you set `app:popUpTo` to the destination you want to pop - you don't want to pop the HomeFragment, you want to pop the StartingFragment, so you should set your `app:popUpTo` to the ID of the StartingFragment.

Note that as per the [Principles of Navigation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-principles#fixed_start_destination), you should always have a fixed starting destination - you shouldn't be using the start destination for [conditional navigation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-conditional) - many of the APIs in Navigation, such as NavigationUI, assume you're correctly following the Principles of Navigation and that the start destination of your graph remains on your back stack.

Keep in mind that Android will restore your state (including what fragment you were at) when returning to your activity (say, after the user manually revoked the permissions you asked for) - your Fragment itself (or the activity if the permission really is globally required on every single screen in your whole app) should always be checking for permission - you can't rely on your StartingFragment always being called.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used the nav lib yet, but from reading [this bit in the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started#pop) maybe you just have a typo and need to replace `popTo` with `popUpTo`?

> To pop destinations when navigating from one destination to another, add a **app:popUpTo** attribute to the associated  element. **app:popUpTo** tells the Navigation library to pop some destinations off of the back stack as part of the call to navigate(). The attribute value is the ID of the most recent destination that should remain on the stack.
>
> You can also include **app:popUpToInclusive="true"** to indicate that the destination specified in **app:popUpTo** should also be removed from the back stack.

Comment: whoops, that was a typo. i did mean `popUpTo`! thanks though